# Tensorflow in windows using python pip

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

Installed python 3.5.2 and also tensorflow using pip command but getting error while importing tensorflow package.
Used command as **import tensorflow as tf** to import tensorflow. But got error as;

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'

How can I rectify this error?
Can I get answer for this as soon as possible..

Comment: Can yo do a `pip freeze` and show the output here?

Comment: appdirs==1.4.3
numpy==1.12.1
packaging==16.8
protobuf==3.3.0
pyparsing==2.2.0
six==1.10.0
tensorflow==1.1.0
Werkzeug==0.12.2
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running on a IDE or ipython or Jupyter?
If yes, it's likely the IDE is using a different python such as virtualenv. It's possible there are multiple pythons installed in your system.

Open cmd and try the following

```
$ where python
$ python -c "import tensorflow"
```

Make sure the path you get is same as the installation path.

If there is still an error, compare with this path

```
$ where pip
```

It's possible your system is using a different python path if there are multiple python.

Comment: I am using powershell . I deleted different paths where python is installed. Still getting the same issue.